# npm install failing on a new folder or any existing project

Tags: node.js, npm

(Windows 11)

I uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs, npm and nvm. currently running node v21.6.2 and npm v10.2.4

This is a new folder with nothing in it

I get error code ENOENT/ error no -4058 when I run
`npm install`
in an empty project folder.

One thing I noticed is that the error path has backward slash (\) the whole path except one before the package.json has forward slash (/), **line 66 below**.

below is the error log

```
58 timing command:install Completed in 32ms
59 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\gk-user\sandbox\hls-apps\package.json'
59 verbose stack     at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:633:25)
59 verbose stack     at async readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1242:14)
59 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\gk-user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v21.6.2\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:165:9)
59 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\gk-user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v21.6.2\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
60 verbose cwd C:\Users\gk-user\sandbox\hls-apps
61 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22631
62 verbose node v21.6.2
63 verbose npm  v10.2.4
64 error code ENOENT
65 error syscall open
66 error path C:\Users\gk-user\sandbox\hls-apps/package.json
67 error errno -4058
68 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\gk-user\sandbox\hls-apps\package.json'
69 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
69 error enoent
70 verbose exit -4058
71 timing npm Completed in 335ms
72 verbose code -4058
```

Comment: `npm install` by its very definition installs dependencies listed in a `package.json` file. If such a file doesn't exist, it throws an error. Are you sure you're not wanting to run `npm init`?

Comment: i really didnt needed that. I was getting a different error when I was doing CRA (create react app) -> cb.apply, which is bascially because it was using npm 5.x even though I did a fresh install of node and npm. somewhere along the way i forgot what I was doing and started doing npm install for no reason. I am an idiot. thanks for pointing me on the right track. i did npm update even though i recently installed it, and everything started working fine...

Comment: Just an FYI but CRA is a dead project. I recommend [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) instead which is roughly equivalent

Comment: thanks again, might check it out. havent done any react in 3+ years, kind of rusty